# Inconsistency in stage and snowflake table data due to data overwritten in stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have scheduled tasks to load data from s3 to snowflake tables using copy into statement.
However, we are observing inconsistency in the data count  due to the below reason:

1. In the case of few tables, data is overwritten for some dates in s3.
2. In snowflake changed data is loaded again but still, old data is
   present.

In what way can we resolve this issue?
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It isn't clear what your issue is. You'll need to add more detail to get a meaningful response here.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake never overwrites existing data. Loading data does not perform an UPDATE, it simply adds data. You can a) delete from the table prior to loading, b) use STREAMs to handle data changes.